# Kinect 4 Windows v2 - Opening recordings

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I've recently obtained a Kinect 4 Windows v2 (time of flight camera).

The Kinect 4 Windows comes with an SDK and a Kinect Studio. The latter allows for monitoring, recording and playback of the cameras on the Kinect. I've been able to successful record and playback a handful of videos for my use.

However, I'm not clear on how to open these recordings in code. The Kinect 4 Windows SDK doesn't seem to support opening the specified file type (XEF). How would one, in code, open a recording?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Kinect Studio is a tool that allows you to simulate pre-recorded data on a sensor level. Basically, it over-rides the sensor stream - your code that works with the sensor thinks that this is real-time, not pre-recorded data. If you think about it, this is a very smart way to do it because you need not to have any special code in your application to test with pre-recorded, static data.

Therefore, these recordings do not open in code. Simply open them in Kinect Studio, click on the Connect button. Then start your application and press Play button in Kinect Studio. Your pre-recorded data will be displayed in your application.